torch.compile - broken data types on uint8 operations?
I am working on a custom quantization kernel + finetuning (but that's offtopic) now.
So the linear quantized kernel forward pass should be
def quant_matmul(x, weight, scale):
    """
    x is a float tensor - float32 / float16
    weight is a bytes tensor (each byte describe 3**5 = 243 parameters) - uint8
    scale is a float number
    """
    batch_size, feature_count = x.shape
    x = x.view((batch_size, feature_count // 5, 5))
    response  = x[:, :, 4] @ ((weight // 3 ** 0) % 3).to(x.dtype) - 1
    response += x[:, :, 3] @ ((weight // 3 ** 1) % 3).to(x.dtype) - 1
    response += x[:, :, 2] @ ((weight // 3 ** 2) % 3).to(x.dtype) - 1
    response += x[:, :, 1] @ ((weight // 3 ** 3) % 3).to(x.dtype) - 1
    response += x[:, :, 0] @ ((weight // 3 ** 4) % 3).to(x.dtype) - 1
    response *= scale
    return response

However I started getting type errors regards (weight // 3 ** (4 - in_group_feature_index) ) % 3 expressions.
So I started investigating them by separating functions:
def three_pow_div(weight, pow):
    response = weight // pow
    return response


def three_division_mod(divided):
    response = divided % 3
    return response


def three_pow_divmod(weight, pow):
    response = three_division_mod(three_pow_div(weight, pow))
    return response

Let's see how it works normally:
three_division_mod(
    three_pow_div(
        torch.ByteTensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]).cuda(),
        3 ** 0,
    )
)

prints me
tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.uint8)

As expected.
"Joined" function:
three_pow_divmod(
    torch.ByteTensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]).cuda(),
    3 ** 0,
)

prints me
tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.uint8)

Basically the same
Now let's see their compiled analogues
torch.compile(three_division_mod)(
    torch.compile(three_pow_div)(
        torch.ByteTensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]).cuda(),
        3 ** 0,
    )
)

tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.uint8)

fine...
Let's see "fused" function.
torch.compile(three_pow_divmod)(
    torch.ByteTensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]).cuda(),
    3 ** 0,
)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BackendCompilerFailed                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 torch.compile(three_pow_divmod)(
      2     torch.ByteTensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]).cuda(),
      3     3 ** 0,
      4 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/eval_frame.py:489, in _TorchDynamoContext.__call__.<locals>._fn(*args, **kwargs)
    487     dynamo_config_ctx.__enter__()
    488 try:
--> 489     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    490 finally:
    491     set_eval_frame(prior)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/eval_frame.py:655, in catch_errors_wrapper.<locals>.catch_errors(frame, cache_entry, frame_state)
    652             return hijacked_callback(frame, cache_entry, hooks, frame_state)
    654 with compile_lock, _disable_current_modes():
--> 655     return callback(frame, cache_entry, hooks, frame_state)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py:727, in convert_frame.<locals>._convert_frame(frame, cache_entry, hooks, frame_state)
    725 counters["frames"]["total"] += 1
    726 try:
--> 727     result = inner_convert(frame, cache_entry, hooks, frame_state)
    728     counters["frames"]["ok"] += 1
    729     return result

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py:383, in convert_frame_assert.<locals>._convert_frame_assert(frame, cache_entry, hooks, frame_state)
    370 signpost_event(
    371     "dynamo",
    372     "_convert_frame_assert._compile",
   (...)
    379     },
    380 )
    382 with config.patch(_patch_config_if_changed()):
--> 383     compiled_product = _compile(
    384         frame.f_code,
    385         frame.f_globals,
    386         frame.f_locals,
    387         frame.f_builtins,
    388         compiler_fn,
    389         one_graph,
    390         export,
    391         export_constraints,
    392         hooks,
    393         cache_size,
    394         frame,
    395         frame_state=frame_state,
    396         compile_id=compile_id,
    397     )
    398 return compiled_product

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py:646, in _compile(code, globals, locals, builtins, compiler_fn, one_graph, export, export_constraints, hooks, cache_size, frame, frame_state, compile_id)
    644 with compile_context(CompileContext(compile_id)):
    645     try:
--> 646         guarded_code = compile_inner(code, one_graph, hooks, transform)
    647         return guarded_code
    648     except (
    649         Unsupported,
    650         TorchRuntimeError,
   (...)
    657         BisectValidationException,
    658     ) as e:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py:244, in dynamo_timed.<locals>.dynamo_timed_inner.<locals>.time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    242 with torch.profiler.record_function(f"{key} (dynamo_timed)"):
    243     t0 = time.time()
--> 244     r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    245     time_spent = time.time() - t0
    246 compilation_time_metrics[key].append(time_spent)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py:562, in _compile.<locals>.compile_inner(code, one_graph, hooks, transform)
    560 CompileContext.get().attempt = attempt
    561 try:
--> 562     out_code = transform_code_object(code, transform)
    563     break
    564 except exc.RestartAnalysis as e:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/bytecode_transformation.py:1033, in transform_code_object(code, transformations, safe)
   1030 instructions = cleaned_instructions(code, safe)
   1031 propagate_line_nums(instructions)
-> 1033 transformations(instructions, code_options)
   1034 return clean_and_assemble_instructions(instructions, keys, code_options)[1]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py:151, in preserve_global_state.<locals>._fn(*args, **kwargs)
    149 cleanup = setup_compile_debug()
    150 try:
--> 151     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    152 finally:
    153     cleanup.close()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py:527, in _compile.<locals>.transform(instructions, code_options)
    525 try:
    526     with tracing(tracer.output.tracing_context), tracer.set_current_tx():
--> 527         tracer.run()
    528 except exc.UnspecializeRestartAnalysis:
    529     speculation_log.clear()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/symbolic_convert.py:2128, in InstructionTranslator.run(self)
   2127 def run(self):
-> 2128     super().run()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/symbolic_convert.py:818, in InstructionTranslatorBase.run(self)
    813 try:
    814     self.output.push_tx(self)
    815     while (
    816         self.instruction_pointer is not None
    817         and not self.output.should_exit
--> 818         and self.step()
    819     ):
    820         pass
    821 except BackendCompilerFailed:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/symbolic_convert.py:781, in InstructionTranslatorBase.step(self)
    777         unimplemented(f"missing: {inst.opname}")
    778     TracingContext.set_current_loc(
    779         self.f_code.co_filename, self.lineno, self.f_code.co_name
    780     )
--> 781     getattr(self, inst.opname)(inst)
    783     return inst.opname != "RETURN_VALUE"
    784 except Unsupported:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/symbolic_convert.py:2243, in InstructionTranslator.RETURN_VALUE(self, inst)
   2238 _step_logger()(
   2239     logging.INFO,
   2240     f"torchdynamo done tracing {self.f_code.co_name} (RETURN_VALUE)",
   2241 )
   2242 log.debug("RETURN_VALUE triggered compile")
-> 2243 self.output.compile_subgraph(
   2244     self,
   2245     reason=GraphCompileReason(
   2246         "return_value", [self.frame_summary()], graph_break=False
   2247     ),
   2248     compile_return_value=True,
   2249 )
   2250 self.output.add_output_instructions([create_instruction("RETURN_VALUE")])

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/output_graph.py:919, in OutputGraph.compile_subgraph(self, tx, partial_convert, reason, compile_return_value)
    916     append_prefix_insts()
    917     # optimization to generate better code in a common case
    918     self.add_output_instructions(
--> 919         self.compile_and_call_fx_graph(tx, list(reversed(stack_values)), root)
    920         + [create_instruction("UNPACK_SEQUENCE", arg=len(stack_values))]
    921     )
    922 else:
    923     graph_output_var = self.new_var("graph_out")

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py:79, in ContextDecorator.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwds)
     76 @wraps(func)
     77 def inner(*args, **kwds):
     78     with self._recreate_cm():
---> 79         return func(*args, **kwds)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/output_graph.py:1087, in OutputGraph.compile_and_call_fx_graph(self, tx, rv, root)
   1084     self.tracing_context.fake_mode = backend_fake_mode
   1086 with self.restore_global_state():
-> 1087     compiled_fn = self.call_user_compiler(gm)
   1088 compiled_fn = disable(compiled_fn)
   1090 counters["stats"]["unique_graphs"] += 1

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py:244, in dynamo_timed.<locals>.dynamo_timed_inner.<locals>.time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    242 with torch.profiler.record_function(f"{key} (dynamo_timed)"):
    243     t0 = time.time()
--> 244     r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    245     time_spent = time.time() - t0
    246 compilation_time_metrics[key].append(time_spent)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/output_graph.py:1159, in OutputGraph.call_user_compiler(self, gm)
   1157     raise e
   1158 except Exception as e:
-> 1159     raise BackendCompilerFailed(self.compiler_fn, e).with_traceback(
   1160         e.__traceback__
   1161     ) from None
   1163 signpost_event(
   1164     "dynamo",
   1165     "OutputGraph.call_user_compiler",
   (...)
   1171     },
   1172 )
   1174 return compiled_fn

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/output_graph.py:1140, in OutputGraph.call_user_compiler(self, gm)
   1138 if config.verify_correctness:
   1139     compiler_fn = WrapperBackend(compiler_fn)
-> 1140 compiled_fn = compiler_fn(gm, self.example_inputs())
   1141 _step_logger()(logging.INFO, f"done compiler function {name}")
   1142 assert callable(compiled_fn), "compiler_fn did not return callable"

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/repro/after_dynamo.py:117, in wrap_backend_debug.<locals>.debug_wrapper(gm, example_inputs, **kwargs)
    115             raise
    116 else:
--> 117     compiled_gm = compiler_fn(gm, example_inputs)
    119 return compiled_gm

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py:1668, in _TorchCompileInductorWrapper.__call__(self, model_, inputs_)
   1665 def __call__(self, model_, inputs_):
   1666     from torch._inductor.compile_fx import compile_fx
-> 1668     return compile_fx(model_, inputs_, config_patches=self.config)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/compile_fx.py:1168, in compile_fx(model_, example_inputs_, inner_compile, config_patches, decompositions)
   1163         return inference_compiler(unlifted_gm, example_inputs_)
   1165 with V.set_fake_mode(fake_mode), torch._guards.tracing(
   1166     tracing_context
   1167 ), compiled_autograd.disable():
-> 1168     return aot_autograd(
   1169         fw_compiler=fw_compiler,
   1170         bw_compiler=bw_compiler,
   1171         inference_compiler=inference_compiler,
   1172         decompositions=decompositions,
   1173         partition_fn=partition_fn,
   1174         keep_inference_input_mutations=True,
   1175     )(model_, example_inputs_)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/backends/common.py:55, in aot_autograd.<locals>.compiler_fn(gm, example_inputs)
     52 try:
     53     # NB: NOT cloned!
     54     with enable_aot_logging(), patch_config:
---> 55         cg = aot_module_simplified(gm, example_inputs, **kwargs)
     56         counters["aot_autograd"]["ok"] += 1
     57         return disable(cg)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py:887, in aot_module_simplified(mod, args, fw_compiler, bw_compiler, partition_fn, decompositions, keep_inference_input_mutations, inference_compiler)
    871 aot_config = AOTConfig(
    872     fw_compiler=fw_compiler,
    873     bw_compiler=bw_compiler,
   (...)
    883     no_tangents=False,
    884 )
    886 with compiled_autograd.disable():
--> 887     compiled_fn = create_aot_dispatcher_function(
    888         functional_call,
    889         full_args,
    890         aot_config,
    891     )
    893 # TODO: There is something deeply wrong here; compiled_fn running with
    894 # the boxed calling convention, but aot_module_simplified somehow
    895 # historically returned a function that was not the boxed calling
    896 # convention.  This should get fixed...
    897 def forward(*runtime_args):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py:244, in dynamo_timed.<locals>.dynamo_timed_inner.<locals>.time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    242 with torch.profiler.record_function(f"{key} (dynamo_timed)"):
    243     t0 = time.time()
--> 244     r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    245     time_spent = time.time() - t0
    246 compilation_time_metrics[key].append(time_spent)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py:600, in create_aot_dispatcher_function(flat_fn, flat_args, aot_config)
    597 compiler_fn = partial(aot_wrapper_dedupe, compiler_fn=compiler_fn)
    598 # You can put more passes here
--> 600 compiled_fn = compiler_fn(flat_fn, fake_flat_args, aot_config, fw_metadata=fw_metadata)
    601 if aot_config.is_export:
    602     mutated_user_inp_locs = [
    603         idx - aot_config.num_params_buffers
    604         for idx in fw_metadata.mutated_inp_runtime_indices
    605         if idx >= aot_config.num_params_buffers
    606     ]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_functorch/_aot_autograd/runtime_wrappers.py:425, in aot_wrapper_dedupe(flat_fn, flat_args, aot_config, compiler_fn, fw_metadata)
    422             break
    424     if ok:
--> 425         return compiler_fn(flat_fn, leaf_flat_args, aot_config, fw_metadata=fw_metadata)
    427     if requires_subclass_dispatch(leaf_flat_args, fw_metadata):
    428         raise RuntimeError(
    429             """\
    430 Encountered duplicate inputs that are mutated in the graph, but at least one input/output
    431 to the graph is a tensor subclass. This is not supported today. You can try to
    432 remove the aliasing yourself as a workaround, or otherwise file an issue on github."""
    433         )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_functorch/_aot_autograd/runtime_wrappers.py:630, in aot_wrapper_synthetic_base(flat_fn, flat_args, aot_config, fw_metadata, needs_autograd, compiler_fn)
    628 # Happy path: we don't need synthetic bases
    629 if synthetic_base_info is None:
--> 630     return compiler_fn(flat_fn, flat_args, aot_config, fw_metadata=fw_metadata)
    632 # export path: ban synthetic bases for now, add later if requested.
    633 if requires_subclass_dispatch(flat_args, fw_metadata):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_functorch/_aot_autograd/jit_compile_runtime_wrappers.py:97, in aot_dispatch_base(flat_fn, flat_args, aot_config, fw_metadata)
     91     if tracing_context := torch._guards.TracingContext.try_get():
     92         tracing_context.fw_metadata = (
     93             fw_metadata
     94             if maybe_subclass_meta is None
     95             else maybe_subclass_meta.fw_metadata
     96         )
---> 97     compiled_fw = compiler(fw_module, updated_flat_args)
     99 # This boxed_call handling happens inside create_runtime_wrapper as well.
    100 # However, create_runtime_wrapper does not expect the rng offsets in the
    101 # output. So, we have to create another wrapper and take out the offset. As
    102 # a result, we have to account for not boxed_call compilers as well.
    103 if not hasattr(compiled_fw, "_boxed_call"):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py:244, in dynamo_timed.<locals>.dynamo_timed_inner.<locals>.time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    242 with torch.profiler.record_function(f"{key} (dynamo_timed)"):
    243     t0 = time.time()
--> 244     r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    245     time_spent = time.time() - t0
    246 compilation_time_metrics[key].append(time_spent)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/compile_fx.py:1100, in compile_fx.<locals>.fw_compiler_base(model, example_inputs, is_inference)
   1092     assert orig_output_end_idx <= num_model_outputs
   1094     user_visible_outputs = {
   1095         n.name
   1096         for n in model_outputs[original_output_start_index:orig_output_end_idx]
   1097         if isinstance(n, torch.fx.Node)
   1098     }
-> 1100 return inner_compile(
   1101     model,
   1102     example_inputs,
   1103     num_fixed=fixed,
   1104     cudagraphs=cudagraphs,
   1105     graph_id=graph_id,
   1106     is_inference=is_inference,
   1107     boxed_forward_device_index=forward_device,
   1108     user_visible_outputs=user_visible_outputs,
   1109 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/repro/after_aot.py:83, in wrap_compiler_debug.<locals>.debug_wrapper(gm, example_inputs, **kwargs)
     78 assert config.repro_after in ("dynamo", "aot", None)
     80 try:
     81     # Call the compiler_fn - which is either aot_autograd or inductor
     82     # with fake inputs
---> 83     inner_compiled_fn = compiler_fn(gm, example_inputs)
     84 except Exception as e:
     85     # TODO: Failures here are troublesome because no real inputs,
     86     # need a different serialization strategy
     87     if config.repro_after == "aot":

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/debug.py:305, in DebugContext.wrap.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
    302 @functools.wraps(fn)
    303 def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    304     with DebugContext():
--> 305         return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py:79, in ContextDecorator.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwds)
     76 @wraps(func)
     77 def inner(*args, **kwds):
     78     with self._recreate_cm():
---> 79         return func(*args, **kwds)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/compile_fx.py:320, in compile_fx_inner(gm, example_inputs, cudagraphs, num_fixed, is_backward, graph_id, cpp_wrapper, aot_mode, is_inference, boxed_forward_device_index, user_visible_outputs, layout_opt, extern_node_serializer)
    316     compiled_graph = FxGraphCache.load(
    317         fx_codegen_and_compile, gm, example_inputs, graph_kwargs
    318     )
    319 else:
--> 320     compiled_graph = fx_codegen_and_compile(
    321         gm, example_inputs, **graph_kwargs  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    322     )
    324 log.debug("FX codegen and compilation took %.3fs", time.time() - start)
    326 # Return the output strides to the caller via TracingContext

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/compile_fx.py:550, in fx_codegen_and_compile(gm, example_inputs, cudagraphs, num_fixed, is_backward, graph_id, cpp_wrapper, aot_mode, is_inference, user_visible_outputs, layout_opt, extern_node_serializer)
    547         else:
    548             output_strides.append(None)
--> 550 compiled_fn = graph.compile_to_fn()
    552 if V.aot_compilation is True:
    553     return compiled_fn

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/graph.py:1116, in GraphLowering.compile_to_fn(self)
   1112     return AotCodeCache.compile(
   1113         self, code, serialized_extern_kernel_nodes, cuda=self.cuda
   1114     )
   1115 else:
-> 1116     return self.compile_to_module().call

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py:244, in dynamo_timed.<locals>.dynamo_timed_inner.<locals>.time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    242 with torch.profiler.record_function(f"{key} (dynamo_timed)"):
    243     t0 = time.time()
--> 244     r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    245     time_spent = time.time() - t0
    246 compilation_time_metrics[key].append(time_spent)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/graph.py:1070, in GraphLowering.compile_to_module(self)
   1068 linemap = [(line_no, node.stack_trace) for line_no, node in linemap]
   1069 key, path = PyCodeCache.write(code)
-> 1070 mod = PyCodeCache.load_by_key_path(
   1071     key, path, linemap=linemap, attrs=self.constants
   1072 )
   1073 self.cache_key = key
   1074 self.cache_path = path

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/codecache.py:1892, in PyCodeCache.load_by_key_path(cls, key, path, linemap, attrs)
   1890 mod.__file__ = path
   1891 mod.key = key  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
-> 1892 exec(code, mod.__dict__, mod.__dict__)
   1893 sys.modules[mod.__name__] = mod
   1894 # another thread might set this first

File /tmp/torchinductor_alex4321/p7/cp7dn63pvxcbtt3jmmwidqiwkaj32dggbs2ff7n3o2hsfnal7ehz.py:68
     64 from torch._inductor.triton_heuristics import grid, start_graph, end_graph
     65 from torch._C import _cuda_getCurrentRawStream as get_cuda_stream
---> 68 async_compile.wait(globals())
     69 del async_compile
     71 def call(args):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/codecache.py:2486, in AsyncCompile.wait(self, scope)
   2484             pbar.set_postfix_str(key)
   2485         if isinstance(result, (Future, TritonFuture)):
-> 2486             scope[key] = result.result()
   2487             pbar.update(1)
   2489 _compile_end()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/codecache.py:2329, in TritonFuture.result(self)
   2327     return self.kernel
   2328 # If the worker failed this will throw an exception.
-> 2329 self.future.result()
   2330 kernel = self.kernel = _load_kernel(self.kernel_name, self.source_code)
   2331 latency = time() - t0

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py:458, in Future.result(self, timeout)
    456     raise CancelledError()
    457 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 458     return self.__get_result()
    459 else:
    460     raise TimeoutError()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bitlinear-numba/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py:403, in Future.__get_result(self)
    401 if self._exception:
    402     try:
--> 403         raise self._exception
    404     finally:
    405         # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
    406         self = None

BackendCompilerFailed: backend='inductor' raised:
CompilationError: at 11:18:def triton_(in_ptr0, out_ptr0, xnumel, XBLOCK : tl.constexpr):
    xnumel = 7
    xoffset = tl.program_id(0) * XBLOCK
    xindex = xoffset + tl.arange(0, XBLOCK)[:]
    xmask = xindex < xnumel
    x0 = xindex
    tmp0 = tl.load(in_ptr0 + (x0), xmask)
    tmp1 = tl.full([1], 1, tl.int16).to(tl.int8).to(tl.uint8)
    tmp2 = tl.where((tmp0 < 0) != (tmp1 < 0), tl.where(tmp0 % tmp1 != 0, tmp0 // tmp1 - 1, tmp0 // tmp1), tmp0 // tmp1)
    tmp3 = tl.full([1], 3, tl.int16).to(tl.int8).to(tl.uint8)
    tmp4 = tmp2 % tmp3
                  ^
ValueError('Cannot use /, #, or % with triton.language.int32 and triton.language.uint8 because they have different signedness;this is unlikely to result in a useful answer. Cast them to the same signedness.')

So as I see in the Triton code (and I am terribly bad with it):

it loaded my weights into tmp0
filled 1-element tensor with 1 (using uint16) than converted to int8 than uint8 (strange but okay) - tmp1 - so tmp1 is a 3^0 = 1-filled array
I don't get what exactly going on with tmp2:

By mask tmp0 % tmp1 != 0 (which should not be true here) it filled some array with tmp0//tmp1 - 1 values, else (which should be used here) with tmp0//tmp1. Fine...
By mask (tmp0 < 0) != (tmp1 < 0) (oh, so the previous one is about signed stuff? But tmp0 should be uint8? And tmp1 were made uint8 explicitly a line ago)...

Well, that should not matter - since being uint8 - tmp0 < 0 should always be false as well as tmp1 < 0
So let's see "else" branch - tmp0 // tmp1. Sounds fine.


So technically speaking tmp2 should be uint8 array?


tmp3 is basically uint8 array filled with 3 - it all told explicitly
So since tmp2 % tmp3 breaks - it means it breaks tmp2 dtype somewhere?

The notebook with reproducing this error:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SJj1biyAmj2RE1t2buUZkhHN_ZM8Bd7x?usp=sharing
By playing with complile backends I see only inductor affected.
p.s. I also tried CPU compilation
torch.compile(three_pow_divmod)(
    torch.ByteTensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]),
    3 ** 0,
)

It failed with basically the same error
/tmp/torchinductor_alex4321/26/c26eqbkuxvn72gf7p2xujmqjcwf4bo6lxmp6rwborxnf4gldnimh.h:147:32: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/torchinductor_alex4321/nx/cnxzbm5rzknle5jpggtkuicz3xsiy5w3wyshqpgrtbud763cmhr3.cpp:14:28: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘T’ (‘int’ and ‘unsigned char’)
   14 |             auto tmp4 = mod(tmp2, tmp3);
      |                         ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~


And CPP code I seen generated was
#include "/tmp/torchinductor_alex4321/26/c26eqbkuxvn72gf7p2xujmqjcwf4bo6lxmp6rwborxnf4gldnimh.h"
extern "C" void kernel(const unsigned char* in_ptr0,
                       unsigned char* out_ptr0)
{
    {
        #pragma GCC ivdep
        for(long x0=static_cast<long>(0L); x0<static_cast<long>(7L); x0+=static_cast<long>(1L))
        {
            auto tmp0 = in_ptr0[static_cast<long>(x0)];
            auto tmp1 = static_cast<unsigned char>(1);
            auto tmp2 = ((tmp0 < 0) != (tmp1 < 0) ? (tmp0 % tmp1 != 0 ? tmp0 / tmp1 - 1 : tmp0 / tmp1) : tmp0 / tmp1);
            auto tmp3 = static_cast<unsigned char>(3);
            auto tmp4 = mod(tmp2, tmp3);
            auto tmp5 = decltype(tmp4)(tmp4 + tmp3);
            auto tmp6 = ((tmp4 != 0) & ((tmp4 < 0) != (tmp3 < 0))) ? tmp5 : tmp4;
            out_ptr0[static_cast<long>(x0)] = tmp6;
        }
    }
}

where auto tmp2 = ((tmp0 < 0) != (tmp1 < 0) ? (tmp0 % tmp1 != 0 ? tmp0 / tmp1 - 1 : tmp0 / tmp1) : tmp0 / tmp1); is really int32.
